# Rails. Add "count" column with sum of values from associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have **Category** table and **Issue** table.

In **Category** model:

```
has_many :issues
```

In **Issue** model:

```
belongs_to :category
```

I am able to write a query that will return the issue_count as a virtual attribute on the collection:

```
Category.left_outer_joins(:issues).select('categories.*, COUNT(issues.*) AS issues_count').group('categories.id')
```

However, I want an actual column on the table that stores the issues_count as a value in the `categories` table, like this:

```
id | name | created_at | updated_at | description | tags | issues_count
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [:counter_cache option](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache):

```ruby
class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  # NOTE: you can also override the default column name
  #       by specifying a custom column name in the counter_cache declaration instead of true
  belongs_to :category, counter_cache: true
end
```

Although the `:counter_cache` option is specified on the model that includes the belongs_to declaration, the actual column must be added to the associated (has_many) model. This will cause the `category.issues_count` field to be updated automatically by ActiveRecord.

You must also create a migration to add this field and update existing records:

```ruby
class AddIssuesCountToCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def up
    add_column :categories, :issues_count, :integer, default: 0
    Category.reset_column_information
    Category.all.each do |c|
      Category.update_counters c.id, issues_count: c.issues.length
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :categories, :issues_count
  end
end
```

Also, Ryan Bates has a good RailsCasts episode on this topic:
[#23 Counter Cache Column](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT categories.*, COUNT(issues.id) as issue_count
FROM categories
INNER JOIN issues
ON issues.category_id = categories.id 
GROUP BY categories.id
```

the above query will do what you need. so in ruby code, it would be like as follows

```
Category.joins(:issues).select("categories.*, COUNT(issues.id) AS issues_count").group('categories.id')
```

Comment: No, this is not what I need. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [`left_outer_join`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins), like this:

```
Category.left_outer_joins(:issues).distinct.select("categories.*, COUNT(issues.*) AS issues_count").group('categories.id')
```

This will generate SQL something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categories.*, COUNT(issues.*) AS issues_count FROM "categories" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "issues" 
    ON "issues"."category_id" = "categories"."id" 
    GROUP BY categories.id
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it returns standard "Category.all" collection, without any extra columns.

Comment: Try doing `categories.first.issues_count` (assuming you've assigned your collection to `categories`).

Comment: No, this is not what I need. I've updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need it to be a query? Otherwise you can write it in your controller like this:

```
@categories = Category.all
```

To get all the issues for each category you can just do

```
@categories.each{|c| puts c.issues.count}
```

or use it the usual way in your views:

```
@categories.each do |c|
```

`c.` ... you can call all columns of category here after the `c.` and 
 `c.issues.count` gives you the count of issues where `category_id` is `c.id`

Else try this:

Category.joins('issues').order('issues.count')

Comment: I need to get collection of full data from Category + one column with sum of issues. I'm using smart_listing gem for sorting table in view and it works with such collections. For sort by name, created_at etc. I can use @categories = Category.all, but I want also sort table by number of issues in each category, so I need to add extra column to "Category.all" collection.

Answer (score -1):

On your controller file -

```
@categories = Category.all
```

It will return all category from category model.

on your view -

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Category Name</th>
  <th>Issue Count</th>
 </tr>
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= category.name %></td>
   <td><%= category.issues.count %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

here we iterate each category by each loop and in second column we just print no. of issues of a category.

Comment: No, this is not what I need. I've updated the question.